# upload multiple files to php server using curl command line

Tags: php, curl

I need to upload multiple files to a server using the curl command line utility. for a single file I have no problem using:

```
curl -F "image=@file1.gif"   http://localhost:8888/web/Upload.php
```

how would I do this with more than one file so that the php variable $_FILES["image"]["error"] would return an array?

I've tried

```
curl -F "image=@file1.gif" -F "image=@file2.gif"  http://localhost:8888/web/Upload.php
curl -F "image=@file1.gif,image=@file2.gif"  http://localhost:8888/web/Upload.php
```

but these are a stab in the dark.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The trick is to name the file uploading parameters unique.

```
curl -F "image=@file1.gif" -F "image2=@file2.gif"  http://localhost:8888/web/Upload.php
```

This will show up in the `$_FILES` superglobal as `$_FILES['image']` and `$_FILES['image2']`.

To make the files grouped under one `$_FILES` index you need to name the parameters as arrays:

```
curl -F "image[]=@file1.gif" -F "image[]=@file2.gif"  http://localhost:8888/web/Upload.php
```

Comment: Actually I'd seen the following page http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php which showed you could upload as an array pictures[]["error"]. i was wondering if that was possible from curl

Comment: this is just for testing a web service which will be used by an iphone app. it will load a numer of images at once

Comment: Oh, that can be achieved witch curl if you name the params as arrays. Updated example.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `curl_multi_init()`. I was working on a project, and since I'm a newbie, not even a year probably, it was terrible hard for me. I needed to upload to a server using an api (anonfiles.com)

**NOTE: My script is based on multiple files input from users. The code is as follows.**

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnUpload'])){
    $total = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
    for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {
      $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
      $filedata = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $filetype = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
      $chfile = new CURLFile($filedata, $filetype, $filename); //creating a CURL object
      $request[]=['file'=>$chfile]; //making an asscoiative array with [1]=>['file'=>'curlobject'] and so on
      $urls[] = "https://api.anonfiles.com/upload?token=ced2abXXXXXXX";//added this each time because this was the only one url
    }

    print_r($request);//just for verification
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($urls);//verification
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    $mh = curl_multi_init(); //initialise multi curl
    foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
        $chs[$key] = curl_init($url);
        //set your own opts, these are the minimum required
        curl_setopt($chs[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($chs[$key], CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($chs[$key], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request[$key]);//adding file data
        curl_setopt($chs[$key], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));//make sure this header is there for it to act like data


        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $chs[$key]);//add them to the handle that we initialised
    }

    //running the requests
    $running = null;
    do {
      curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($running);

    //getting the responses
    $responsearray = array();//Just to store the responses
    foreach(array_keys($chs) as $key){
        $error = curl_error($chs[$key]);
        $last_effective_URL = curl_getinfo($chs[$key], CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); 
        $time = curl_getinfo($chs[$key], CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME);//response time
        $response = curl_multi_getcontent($chs[$key]);  // get results
        array_push($responsearray, $response);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $chs[$key]);//removing it as a handle
    }
    // close current handler
    curl_multi_close($mh);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    print_r($responsearray);
}
```