# What is the right way to POST multipart/form-data using curl?

Tags: forms, post, curl

I used this syntax to post a file along with some parameters:

```
curl -v -include --form "key1=value1" --form upload=localfilename URL
```

The file is around 500K in size. First of all, I see content length to be 254 on the transmit side. Later the server response's content length is 0. 
Where am I going wrong?

Here is the complete trace of the command.

```
* Couldn't find host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx in the _netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port yyyy (#0)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x4b96a0
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x4b96a0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port yyyy (#0)
* POST /zzzzzz/UploadFile HTTP/1.1
* User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
* Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy
* Accept: */*
* Content-Length: 254
* Expect: 100-continue
* Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------948a6137eef50079
*
* HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

* HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
* Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
* Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
* Added cookie JSESSIONID="C1D7DD042E250211D9DEA82688876F88" for domain xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, path /zzzzz/, expire 0
* Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C1D7DD042E250211D9DEA82688876F88; Path=/zzzzzz/;
* HttpOnly
* Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C1D7DD042E250211D9DEA82688876F88; Path=/zzzzzz/; HttpOnly
* Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
* Content-Length: 0
* Content-Length: 0
* Date: Tue, 01 Oct 2013 11:54:24 GMT
* Date: Tue, 01 Oct 2013 11:54:24 GMT
* Connection #0 to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx left intact
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using curl to upload POST data with files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files)

Answer (score 402, accepted):

The following syntax fixes it for you:

```
curl -v -F key1=value1 -F upload=@localfilename URL
```

Comment: what about Windows & curl.exe ?

Comment: what about multiple attachments?

Comment: It works exactly the same on Windows and.it supports multiple "attachments"/files: just add more -F instances!

Comment: This answer has a good example of uploading multiple files.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599957/upload-multiple-files-to-php-server-using-curl-command-line

Comment: This works.  on curl we do not need to add something like this: `-H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' `

Comment: @hellboy "upload" is the field name, add other one with other field name

Comment: @hellboy ["To send multiple files, repeat the -F option several times."](https://reqbin.com/req/c-dot4w5a2/curl-post-file#:~:text=To%20send%20multiple%20files%2C%20repeat%20the%20%2DF%20option%20several%20times.)

Comment: @Emily — The content-type header is needed, but cURL will generate it for you.

Answer (score 38):

This is what worked for me

```
curl --form file='@filename' URL
```

---

#### Edit...

It seems when I gave this answer (*8+ years ago*), I didn't really understand the question, or how form fields worked. I was just answering based on what I had tried in a difference scenario, and it worked for me.

So firstly, the only mistake the OP made was in not using the `@` symbol before the file name. Secondly, my answer which uses `file=...` only worked for me because the form field I was trying to do the upload for was called `file`. If your form field is called something else, use that name instead.

##### Explanation

From the `curl` [manpages](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html); under the description for the option [`--form`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-F) it says:

> This enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content'
> part to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get
> the content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a
> file  get
> attached in the post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a
> file.

Chances are that if you are trying to do a form upload, you will most likely want to use the `@` prefix to upload the file rather than `<` which uploads the *contents* of the file.

##### Addendum

Now I must also add that one must be careful with using the `<` symbol because in most unix shells, `<` is the input redirection symbol *[which coincidentally will also supply the contents of the given file to the standard input of the program before `<`]*. This means that if you do not properly escape that symbol or wrap it in quotes, you may find that your `curl` command does not behave the way you expect.

On that same note, I will also recommend quoting the `@` symbol.

---

You may also be interested in this other question: [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data), because `curl` offers other ways of uploading a file, but they differ in the content-type set in the header. For example the [`--data`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) option offers a similar mechanism for uploading files as data, but the `Content-Type` header is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` whereas with `--file`, it is set to `multipart/form-data`.

---

Anyways, that's all I wanted to say about this answer since it started to get more upvotes. I hope this helps erase any confusions such as the difference between this answer and the [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19148720/2089675) answer. There is really none, except for this explanation.

Answer (score 29):

to upload a file using curl in Windows I found that the path requires escaped double quotes

e.g.

```
curl -v -F 'upload=@\"C:/myfile.txt\"' URL
```

Comment: This answer helped me a lot. Though in my case I should not escape `"`, that is in my case on Mac I should send it like `curl -X POST -F key1=value1 -F 'image=@"/Users/ivkremer/Downloads/file name.jpg"'`;

Comment: in my case - I had a success transfer without any quotes :   curl -v -F file=@/Users/path/to/file/testq.jpg http://192.168.0.101:8080/upload-image

Comment: In my case in Windows, I could not use the single quotes and had to use double quotes like this `curl -F "filename=@\"C:\temp\file.jpg\"" https://someurl.com`

Answer (score 4):

I had a hard time sending a multipart HTTP PUT request with `curl` to a Java backend. I simply tried

```sh
curl -X PUT URL \
   --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------BOUNDARY' \
   --data-binary @file
```

and the content of the file was

```
-----------BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name1"
Content-Type: application/xml;version=1.0;charset=UTF-8

<xml>content</xml>
-----------BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name2"
Content-Type: text/plain

content
-----------BOUNDARY--
```

but I always got an error that the boundary was incorrect. After some Java backend debugging I found out that the Java implementation was adding a `\r\n--` as a prefix to the boundary, so after changing my input file to

```
                          <-- here's the CRLF
-------------BOUNDARY       <-- added '--' at the beginning
...
-------------BOUNDARY       <-- added '--' at the beginning
...
-------------BOUNDARY--     <-- added '--' at the beginning
```

everything works fine!

#### **tl;dr**

Add a newline (CRLF `\r\n`) at the beginning of the multipart boundary content and `--` at the beginning of the boundaries and try again.

Maybe you are sending a request to a Java backend that needs this changes in the boundary.

Comment: When copying POST data with Firefox web console, I also noticed that it was using `\n` instead of `\r\n`. Even mitmproxy copy as cURL was using `\n` so I had to copy the raw request with mitmproxy. I saw with hexdump that it was using hex code `0A` instead of `0D 0A`.

Comment: the `\r\n` is required. Look at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-5.1.1 page 19.

Comment: 1. What Java backend framework was that backend based on? 
2. Can you please paste the full working `curl` command?

Comment: the `curl` command doesn't change, just the multipart input file where I added the `\r\n--`. Framework was Spring Surf

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10, curl 7.28.1 within powershell, I found the following to work for me:

```
$filePath = "c:\temp\dir with spaces\myfile.wav"
$curlPath = ("myfilename=@" + $filePath)
curl -v -F $curlPath URL
```

Answer (score 0):

**With Smartbear Zephyr Scale, server version, you would attach a file to a Test Cycle this way :**

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic YkskfdygyzghhMg==" -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" https://jira/jira/rest/atm/1.0/testrun/TDLT-C32/attachments --form file="@file2.txt"
```

(returns {"id":7099})

**where in file2.txt : Test Cycle has also a link to a test plan, and a link to an issue.**

```
{
  "projectKey": "TDD",
  "testPlanKey": "TDD-P1",
  "name": "Bonjour chez vous, Le Prisonnier",
  "issueKey": "TDLT-999"
  }
```

I'm posting this since unable to find that out from official documentation :)

Answer (score -4):

Maybe this form work

curl -X POST -d 'key1=value1&key2=value2' http://URL -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: clearly the OP is asking for multipart form data, not application urlencoded