# Linux CURL how to POST file and data url encoded same time?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, urlencode

I have a problem to send a POST request with a text file and some key=value (value contains special characters and it needs to be encoded, e.g: query=select c + a % b).

I've tried like this and it returns error `Warning: You can only select one HTTP request!`

```
curl -F "file=@path_to_text_file" 
--data-urlencode "query=select c + a % b" "http://localhost:8082/app"
```

remove `--data-urlencode` then it can run but the value of query is not encoded.

I prefer to not need to encode query manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right way to POST multipart/form-data using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116016/what-is-the-right-way-to-post-multipart-form-data-using-curl)

Comment: @DmitriChubarov these topics only contain key=value which doesn't have the special characters.

Comment: The accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19148720/1328439 should solve it for you. To encode the query string use `urllib.urlencode()`

Comment: @DmitriChubarov this is not what I wanted to use an external tool to encode, thanks though.

Comment: You can specify exactly one content-type for one POST request. It can be either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, or `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain` but you have to use only one. For your command `curl` was complaining that you are trying to specify both `form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: this helps with your detail answer. I think there is no choice as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the upload then send the post request

`curl -F "file=@path_to_text_file" "http://localhost:8082/app" --next 
--data-urlencode "query=select c + a % b" "http://localhost:8082/app"`

Comment: unfortunately, the --next parameter only exists since version 7.36. In Centos 7, it is version 7.29 only.