# How to fill php form type:multipart/form-data with multiple files in powershell

Tags: php, forms, powershell, multipartform-data

I cannot POST a php form with two files in powershell

I search the equivalent of the bash command :
    /usr/bin/curl -F fichier1=@/path_to_file1 -F fichier2=@/path_to_file2\MyUrl.com

The Php form "formulaire" wait two parameters :
"fichier1" type file
and "fichier2" type file

I've tried to follow the resolution of [What is the right way to POST multipart/form-data using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116016/what-is-the-right-way-to-post-multipart-form-data-using-curl/31619357) but i have the error message A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'F'
I've tried to use the Invoke-Method with -Infile parameter but it accepts only one string parameter and I can't pass my two files path
Hère is my code :

```
$Uri = "//MyUrl.com/backups/uploadLogsVms.php"
$filePath="C:\backup_points.csv"
$filePath2="C:\PROTECTED_VMS_JOB_SCHEDULE_2018_12_10.csv"
curl -v -F fichier1=@"$filePath" -F fichier2=@"$filePath2"
```

I expected to fill the form below and press the button boutEnvoyer with a powershell script:

```
<body>
<form name='formulaire' id='formulaire' method='post' action='/backups/uploadLogsVms.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
     <input type='file' name='fichier1' id='fichier' size='60' /><br />
     <input type='file' name='fichier2' id='fichier' size='60' /><br />
     <input type='submit' class='bouton' id='boutEnvoyer' value='Envoyer' />
</form>
</body></html>
```

witch is equivalent to my bash command /usr/bin/curl -F fichier1=@/path_to_file1 -F fichier2=@/path_to_file2  http://MyUrl.com/backups/uploadLogs.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution

I've downloaded powershell 6.2 version [powershell 6.2 preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-6) and now the -Form parameter works !

and I correct my code to

```
 $Uri = 'http://MyUrl.com/backups/uploadLogsVms.php'
$Form = @{
    fichier1     = Get-Item -Path 'C:\users\ADM_2N\Desktop\PROTECTED_VMS_JOB_SCHEDULE_2018_12_10.csv'
    fichier2     = Get-Item -Path 'C:\users\adm_2n\Desktop\backup_points.csv'

}
$Result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Post -Form $Form
```