# Yii2 file upload via console and web

Tags: php, yii2

I want to implement a file upload in my Yii2 application. This should be possible via Web and Console command.

Is there a helper in Yii2, so I can use the same implementation? (I started with `yii\web\UploadFile` for the web frontend and realized that I can't use that for the console command)

The `yii\web\UploadFile` class is designed to work with `ActiveForm`, or more specifically with the `$_FILES` content.

Comment: How you want to upload file with console? Just copy/move the file from one place to another?

Comment: I was hoping there is a helper like yii\web\UploadedFile, which can be used for console commands (Yii console commands!), but I guess that is not the case.

Comment: `UploadedFile` work with `$_FILES` array, which get data from HTTP POST. So, you cannot use `UploadedFile` directly to work with CLI. As variant, you can try to use `curl` [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599957/upload-multiple-files-to-php-server-using-curl-command-line).

Comment: Yes I indicated that in the initial Post. Ok, no problem to find a way, but thanks anyway for your comments.

Comment: may be you can try run a script with input as file path to mv file from source folder (input) to destination folder.