# Uploading a file to Python bottle server without HTML form

Tags: python, file, upload, bottle

Currently I have an HTML form which chooses the file and upload it to server.
How to do it without HTML form.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  Select a file: <input type="file" name="uploadinc" />
  <input type="submit" value="Start upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my bottle server contains the following code to upload.

```
@route('/UploadFiles', method='POST')
def UploadFiles():
   print "inside upload files"
   uploadinc = request.files.get('uploadinc')

   uploadinc.save("/home/user/files/"+uploadinc.filename)
```

I want to directly save the file without HTML UI.

Like..

```
   request.files.get("file location in local machine if it is fixed(C:\\a.txt)")
```

But it is getting as none. How to do it?

I am able to call the Rest API from a rest client like this.

[image: Calling REST api with multipart form data]

How to do this call programatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try [Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) lib: [POST a Multipart-Encoded File](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

> How to do this call programatically ?

Modified example from Requests lib [documentation](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files):

```
import requests
url = 'http://10.208.53.89:7778/UploadFiles'
multiple_files = [
   ('images', ('foo.png', open('foo.png', 'rb'), 'image/png')),
   ('images', ('bar.png', open('bar.png', 'rb'), 'image/png'))
]
r = requests.post(url, files=multiple_files)
```

Comment: please see updated answer.. I am able to make rest call from rest client

Answer (score 1):

You want to upload files from the command line, instead of in a browser?  Just use curl:

```
curl -F "image=@foo.png" -F "image2=@bar.png"  http://localhost:8888/uploadFiles
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599957/upload-multiple-files-to-php-server-using-curl-command-line).