# windows curl command line won't accept an array of files

Tags: windows, curl, lamp

I'm trying to upload a set of 3 files simultaneously to a LAMP server using the command line version of curl on Windows.  The following command ([referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11601341)) works perfectly on the linux version but doesn't send any files on when I try it on Windows port:

```
curl.exe -F file[]=@1.jpg -F file[]=@2.mp4 -F file[]=3.mp4 https://www.blah.com/upload.php
```

upload.php accepts and processes the files:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $total = count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
               //process files
        }
 }
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what was `upload.php` do?

Comment: accepts and processes the files.  I'll add a piece of the code.

Comment: the PHP file works with multifile uploads. from linux curl, but only w/ a single file at a time with Windows curl.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has trouble with this, I was able to get this to work by with following command:

```
curl.exe -F file1=@1.jpg -F file2=@2.mp4 -F file3=3.mp4 https://www.blah.com/upload.php
```

Then with php I iterated through the files like so:

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        foreach($_FILES as $file){
            $tempFile = $file['tmp_name'];
            $name       = $file['name'];
            //do something...
        }
}
```