# Upload image to PHP server using cURL?

Tags: php, curl, server, debian, ubuntu-16.04

Using a very simple PHP server:

```
<?php
$file = date("YmdHisms") . ".jpg";
file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents("php://input"));
?>
```

I'm trying to upload images using cURL:

```
curl --data "/path/to/image.jpg" 'http://192.168.1.3'
```

or:

[upload multiple files to php server using curl command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599957/upload-multiple-files-to-php-server-using-curl-command-line)

```
curl -F "image=@image.jpg" 'http://192.168.1.3'
```

or:

```
cat image.jpg | curl --data - 'http://192.168.1.3'
```

Files are getting created in my web sever directory, but the images don't seem to open? What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the php code to

```
<?php
   $file = date("YmdHisms") . ".jpg";
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "image=@image.jpg" http://192.168.1.3
```